# PJSIP on iOS7 iPhone5 no outbound audio but works in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, voip, pjsip

I'm using the Gossip wrapper and the latest version of PJSIP to create a soft phone.

- When making calls between the iOS simulator (iOS7) and an iPod (iOS6) I get two way audio (signaling over TCP or UDP both work).
- When making an outbound call from iPhone5 (iOS7) to iPod (iOS6) or Simulator (iOS7) I can't hear caller audio from the callee side, but can hear the audio from iPod or Sim on the caller side. Wireshark shows two RTP streams although since they are Speex I can't verify that audio is transmitted from the iPhone side (since wireshark doesn't decode Speex).
- When receiving an inbound call to iPhone from iPod or Sim I get the same one way audio as above however I only see one RTP stream (iPod/Sim -> iPhone).

I've set PJSIP log level to 6 and I get no audio errors. I've also verified the sound and audio device ids across iPod, iPhone and Simulator during the in-call state and tried using pjsua_set_snd_dev to map all possible combinations of audio device ids returned by pjsua_enum_snd_dev.

I have verified that the iPhone's microphone works by making a cellular call and I've also verified that the AudioToolbox can find a mic like so:

```
// check if mic is available
UInt32 hasMicro, size;
size = sizeof(hasMicro);
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioInputAvailable,
                        &size, &hasMicro);
```

Is anyone familiar with this problem or with a method for further diagnosis?

Comment: Hi there! I've got exactly same issue on iPhone 5. Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using PJSUA2 for VoIP on iPhone5. Telnet example works fine with the library build. 
No audio on either side when used PJSUA2 wrapper lib or cpp.